# How does option method works in PHP/Laravel? ( Route::options($uri, $callback); )

Tags: php, laravel, methods

Where we can use it with it's full potential?
From laravel I can see no proper explanation. I need a clear concept about it.

Answer (score 0):

The laravel docs is not very comprehensive about [cors](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#cors), but since version 9.2 the following [middleware](https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors) is included.

Basically you configure the cors options in `config/cors.php` example:

```php
<?php

return [
    'paths' => ['api/*'],
    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],
    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],
    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],
    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],
    'exposed_headers' => [],
    'max_age' => 0,
    'supports_credentials' => false,
];
```